# Angular Material cant change background color with theme

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design, angular-material-theming

I've been tring to make a custom theme for my site but nothing will effect the background color. This is my theme:

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
@include mat-core();

$warn: mat-palette($mat-red);

$dark-primary: mat-palette($mat-grey, 900);
$dark-accent: mat-palette($mat-grey);
$dark-theme: mat-dark-theme($dark-primary, $dark-accent, $warn);
@include angular-material-theme($dark-theme);

$blue-primary: mat-palette($mat-indigo, 800, 100, 100);
$blue-accent: mat-palette($mat-grey, 300, 100, 500);
$blue-theme: mat-light-theme($blue-primary, $blue-accent, $warn);

.alt-theme {
    @include angular-material-theme($blue-theme);
}
```

I have `mat-app-background` on my body but what ever the first included theme is set to dark/light that is what the background color is changed too, black or white.

This was a problem at first but I'm fine with that my issue now is that it doesnt care that the alt-theme is light, the background stays black. Or if the first included theme is light and the alt is dark it will stay white.

EDIT:

So my issue was that I was adding the class to my `mat-drawer-container` which I guess it doesnt like, I wrapped it in a div and then everything started working as expected

Comment: Are you appling the .alt-theme css class to any component or to your html body?
You are just including the dark-theme. If you want  to activate the .alt-theme you have to use an overlay i think

Comment: Yes I am applying the class.

Comment: The issue is isnt that the theme isnt being applied the issue is that when it does get applied the background color doesnt change with it

Answer (score -2):

I usually add variables like these:

```
$mat-light-theme-background: (
  status-bar: map_get($mat-grey, 300),
  app-bar:    map_get($mat-grey, 100),
  background: map_get($mat-grey, A100),
  hover:      rgba(black, 0.04), // TODO(kara): check style with Material Design UX
  card:       white,
  dialog:     white,
  disabled-button: $black-12-opacity,
  raised-button: white,
  focused-button: $black-6-opacity,
  selected-button: map_get($mat-grey, 300),
  selected-disabled-button: map_get($mat-grey, 400),
  disabled-button-toggle: map_get($mat-grey, 200),
  unselected-chip: map_get($mat-grey, 300),
  disabled-list-option: map_get($mat-grey, 200),
);

$mat-light-theme-foreground: (
  base:              black,
  divider:           $dark-dividers,
  dividers:          $dark-dividers,
  disabled:          $dark-disabled-text,
  disabled-button:   rgba(black, 0.26),
  disabled-text:     $dark-disabled-text,
  hint-text:         $dark-disabled-text,
  secondary-text:    $dark-secondary-text,
  icon:              rgba(black, 0.54),
  icons:             rgba(black, 0.54),
  text:              rgba(black, 0.87),
  slider-min:        rgba(black, 0.87),
  slider-off:        rgba(black, 0.26),
  slider-off-active: rgba(black, 0.38),
);

// Create the theme object (a Sass map containing all of the palettes).
$material-theme: mat-light-theme($primary, $accent, $warn);
```

Comment: How do you apply the foreground and background? I did try just adding the code to my scss file but nothing changed